# Learning a Linear Model in Python in the form of y =a*x+b

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am currently working in python attempting to learn how to do linear regressions using the Fortune 500 dataset. So far I have cleaned my dataset by removing N.As. However, as I have reached Problem D I am not sure how to approach building this model. Based on the instructions I am assuming for x I am to use Revenues (in millions), however, I do not know what else should be in X. How can I continue and build this model?

Part B: Clean up the dataset by removing the records (rows) whose profits are N.A. and look into the relationship between revenues and profits.

```
dfCleanX = df[ df['Profit (in millions)']!='N.A.']
dfCleanX.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Int64Index: 25131 entries, 0 to 25499

Data columns (total 5 columns):

Year                     25131 non-null int64

Rank                     25131 non-null int64

Revenue (in millions)    25131 non-null float64

Profit (in millions)     25131 non-null object

Company                  25131 non-null object

dtypes: float64(1), int64(2), object(2)

memory usage: 1.2+ MB

dfClean = dfCleanX.astype({'Profit (in millions)': 'float64'})

print(dfClean.values.shape )

dfClean.info()

(25131, 5)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 25131 entries, 0 to 25499
Data columns (total 5 columns):
Year                     25131 non-null int64
Rank                     25131 non-null int64
Revenue (in millions)    25131 non-null float64
Profit (in millions)     25131 non-null float64
Company                  25131 non-null object
dtypes: float64(2), int64(2), object(1)
memory usage: 1.2+ MB

dfClean.plot.scatter(x='Revenue (in millions)', y='Profit (in millions)')

<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x23e0222a3c8>
```

Part C: In this part, let's focus on cases with "positive profits" only. We want to examine the relationship between revenue (i.e. x) and profit (i.e, y) to build a linea model y = a*x+b

Visualize the relationship of y vs x where y and x are profits(>0) and revenues.

```py
positiveProfitMask = dfClean['Profit (in millions)'] > 0
dfClean[ positiveProfitMask  ].plot.scatter(
    x='Revenue (in millions)', 
    y='Profit (in millions)'
    )

<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x23e023b8358>
```

**Problem D**: Focus on the cases with "positive profits" only. Fill in the missing code in the cell below to

1. learn a linear model in the form of y =a*x+b to model the relationship between revenues (i.e. x) and positive profits (i.e, y),
2. use the model to find the predicted profits for these cases, and
3. plot the predictions along with the data to see how the model fit the data.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x = dfClean[(Revenues (in millions) )][??? ]
y = dfClean[( Profits (in millions) )][??? ]

model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
model.fit(positiveProfitMask  , y)

print( "model.coef_ =", model.coef_ )
print( "model.intercept_ =", model.intercept_ )
print( "Linear model about y(profit) and x(revenue): y=",  
       model.coef_, '* x +', model.intercept_)
yfit = model.predict(???  )

plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.plot(x, yfit, 'r');
```

Answer (score 1):

If only following line `yfit = model.predict(???  )` needs to be filled in then you need to just pass a vector X, to see what your model will predict for given values. Since you only need positive profits you need to filter that our first from your X.

Heres how you can do it in `pandas`:

```
 cleaned_df = df[df['profit'] > 0]
 y = df['y'].values
 X = df.drop(columns=['y']).values

 yfit = model.predict(X)
```

Comment: I still need to fill out the question marks in X, y: x = dfClean[(Revenues (in millions) )][??? ]
y = dfClean[( Profits (in millions) )][??? ]

Comment: @vane I dont think thats an actual line of code that needs to be filled out. Looks more like a pseudocode. The code I suggested does just what you need